# How do I find the all valid pairings between two sets?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

First of all: It doesn't matter in which programming language you can solve this, it will be easy for me to convert it to any other.

I have a pretty hard problem to solve here, and I have no idea how to start. I have X kind of fruits and **EXACTLY 5 colors** (let's say Red, Green, Yellow, Blue and Purple). Each fruit can be available in several colors (but in at least 1). How can I find each combination, when I need **exactly 1 fruit of each color but no fruit twice** (so there will always be bought **exactly 5 different fruits in exactly 5 different colors**)?

For example:

```
1. Pears are available in [Red, Green, Yellow]
2. Apples are available in [Red, Green]
3. Plums are available in [Purple]
4. Grapes are available in [Red, Green, Purple]
5. Bananas are available in [Blue, Yellow]
```

Since bananas are the only fruit available in blue, it's already sure, that bananas will be bought in blue, and not in yellow.

These would be the solution for this list:

```
1. Yellow Pear, Red Apple, Purple Plum, Green Grapes, Blue Banana
2. Yellow Pear, Green Apple, Purple Plum, Red Grapes, Blue Banana
```

No other combination is possible here. Is there any algorithm to do this with a dynamic list, which may also have more than 5 fruits?

I know, it's a pretty hard problem, but maybe someone has a simple solution for it.

Comment: For such a little problem you can simply test all $5^{5}$ combinations an check for validity. [or use Backtracking]

Comment: Yes, that's what I try. But I still have no idea how to do this. Is there a simple way to create a 2D array out of 2 1D arrays?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the problem can be modelled as a [bipartite matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29); here the colors would constitute one partition while the fruits constitute the other partition. an edge between color `c` and fruit `f` exists if and only if fruit `f` is available in color `c`. The objective is to cover all colors.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I also found out about [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) when looking for a solution. But unfortunately I can't imagine how to solve this by coding..

Comment: @SoBiT You can use [Ford-Fulkerson](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) for a simple implementation. The runtime in your case will be O(X) if you place the colors on the left side of the graph

Comment: The bipartite matching problem can be solved by the so-called hungarian algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm or, if available, by using an auxiliary network flow problem.

Comment: @Codor Hungerian is overly complicated and slow for unweighted matching. It is typically used to solve maximum-weight matching (assignment problem)

Comment: @NiklasB. Perhaps you are right, I never implemented or tried out the hungarian algorithm myself; your reference seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Codor and also I don't have a third parameter like cost. I just need to find any possible combination

Comment: @SoBiT *any* possible or *all* possible combinations. Note that there might be exponentially many solutions

Comment: @Codor Right, sorry, I mean ALL possible solutions. And note: There are always exactly 5 colors, but there might be 9 fruits for example. Both of your solutions have only examples with fruitCount = colorCount

Comment: @SoBiT If _all_ combinations are required, backtracking seems to be optimal; indeed there might be a number of solutions which is exponential in both the number of colors and the number of fruits.